# Cannot delete a parent row: a foreign key constraint fail

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 entities (User , Teacher) the User is the father ...

When I want to remove user by native query it give me this error ( `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fail` )

Though I have written:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user_id",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL  , orphanRemoval = true )
```

at the *Teacher* reference in the user entity
but when I try to use JPA derived method *deleteByEmail()* .. it worked!

What is the reason?

Comment: enable sql logging i guess spring data jpa might be executing 2 SQL queries to delete these rows.

Comment: Enable the SQL logging in JPA and you will see the difference in queries for both cases. In first case the delete is failing because of foreign key constraint. For second case most likely the child delete is happening first so it does not causes issue.

Comment: yeah i know , thats what happend , but with the native query it must delete also the 2 entities because of the cascad type right !!!??

Answer (score 0):

Cascading doesn't work with queries.

It works when you change the state of the entities using the methods in the `EntityManager` or Hibernate ORM `Session`.

You can see a list of examples in the Hibernate ORM documentation:
[5.15. Cascading entity state transitions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade).